# how to select only one row from all columns but the first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is such a thing even possible to do? For an application I'm trying to make, a user can enter multiple (or no) emails, phone numbers and addresses for a single contact, however on the front-facing page, I only want to display the *first* phone number, email address, and address for each contact (if there is one).

Here is my SQL query for retrieving the data (note that it's been slightly modified for readability. In practice, I'm not querying SQL for a cookie.):

```
SELECT TC.FirstName + ' ' + TC.LastName AS FullName, TCE.EmailAddress, TCPN.PhoneNumber, TCA.[Address] + ", " + TCA.City + ', ' + TCA.[State] + ', ' + TCA.ZipCode AS FullAddress, TC.Notes
FROM TContacts                  AS TC
INNER JOIN TContactEmails       AS TCE ON TCE.ContactID = TC.ContactID
INNER JOIN TContactPhoneNumbers AS TCPN ON TCPN.ContactID = TC.ContactID
INNER JOIN TContactAddresses    AS TCA ON TCA.ContactID = TC.ContactID
INNER JOIN TUserContacts        AS TUC ON TUC.ContactID = TC.ContactID
INNER JOIN TUsers               AS TU ON TU.UserID = TUC.UserID
WHERE TU.UserName = userCookie.Values["UserName"]
```

The desired result would be something similar to using `SELECT TOP 1` instead of just `SELECT`, however I cannot do that specifically, because then it would only display the first contact (FullName). I need to see every name, but not every FullAddress, PhoneNumber, or EmailAddress.

The following info is for if there is another solution not related to the SQL query specifically.

This SQL query is getting utilized in a webpage using ASP.NET and C# code and being called via ADO.NET commands. Once the query is called, all tables utilized are loaded into a DataAdapter object and used to dynamically fill a ListView. Here is the code for that (sqlStatement omitted because it is essentially listed above):

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CPDM_NightingaleAConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "TUsers, TUserContacts, TContactAddresses, TContactPhoneNumbers, TContactPhoneNumbers, TContactEmails, TContacts");
        lvContacts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        lvContacts.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
```

The ASP.NET code for the ListView dynamically creates a table based on the values, like so:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvContacts" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhoneNumber") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullAddress") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>' /></td>
            </tr>      
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

This is by no means the most elegant implementation of a feature such as this, but as it stands, I am no expert at any of the tools I am using. Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

As an addendum, if anyone happens to know how to add a line break in the middle of a SQL SELECT statement that will show when converted to HTML, it would be of great use for organizing the FullAddress. `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` did seemingly nothing of value.

Comment: As for the line break, it may be better to leave the address separate in your SQL statement and break it down in your Link Button code using `<%# Eval("Address") + Environment.NewLine + Eval("City") + ", " + Eval("State") + " " + Eval("ZipCode") %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery which is usually good for these types of lookups:

```
SELECT TC.FirstName + ' ' + TC.LastName AS FullName, 
(SELECT TOP 1 EmailAddress FROM TContactEmails WHERE ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS EmailAddress, 
(SELECT TOP 1 PhoneNumber FROM TContactPhoneNumbers WHERE ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS PhoneNumber,
(SELECT TOP 1 [Address] + ", " + City + ', ' + [State] + ', ' + ZipCode FROM TContactAddresses WHERE ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS FullAddress, 
TC.Notes
FROM TContacts                  AS TC
INNER JOIN TUserContacts        AS TUC ON TUC.ContactID = TC.ContactID
INNER JOIN TUsers               AS TU ON TU.UserID = TUC.UserID
WHERE TU.UserName = userCookie.Values["UserName"]
```

Alternatively, use a "Default" boolean in the table and let the user entering the data save their default address, phone number, etc.

Comment: This is an answer too, but if you have large amount of records in TContac, outer apply perform much better than subquery.

Comment: I haven't analyzed the performance, so I'm not sure. But at least we gave him/her more than one option. :)

Comment: @BoydP Thank you! This works flawlessly. My program is pretty small so scale won't be an issue, but Flicker, thank you for your response as well. I didn't even know cross joins existed until now, and I did see your edit to outer apply, so I will take a look to see if I can get that to work later, but for now this suits my needs. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: No problem. outer apply is very help full.

Comment: some times outer apply perform much faster than join and sub-query. but for your case I think sub-query is better choice. I did some test and sub-query was better.

Comment: You are welcome. I've been doing lots of these types of queries myself lately, so it was good to also learn about the CROSS JOIN and APPLY.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first Phone for every Contact using Cross Join (not inner join) like below generic example

```
select TC.*, pho.Phone, adr.[Address]
from TContact AS TC
  outer apply (select top 1 phone
              from TContactPhoneNumbers
              where ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS pho
  outer apply (select top 1 [address] 
              from TContactAddresses
              where ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS adr
  outer apply (select top 1 [UserName] 
              from TUserContacts
              where ContactID = TC.ContactID) AS uc
  outer apply (select top 1 [UserName] 
              from TUsers
              where UserId = uc.UserID) AS u
where u.UserName = what ever .....
```

and add other tables as you see...

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for, but how does the where clause work? I'm trying to use `WHERE TContactPhoneNumbers.ContactID = TContacts.ContactID`, but I keep getting a "multi-part identifier TContacts.ContactID could not be bound" error.

Comment: Are you aliasing the table? If you did as Flicker suggested "TContacts as tc" then you have to use tc.ContactID, not TContacts.ContactID.

Comment: @BoydP I did try that first, both TC.ContactID (with the AS TC) and TContacts.ContactID (without the AS TC) result in the same error.

Comment: I just posted some generic example. did not use exactly what is in you query. I make some changes. take a look again